# How to prove or disprove finiteness?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

How to prove or disprove that statement: a group is finite if the set of all its subgroups is finite?

Comment: Suppose every $a\in G$ generates a finite subgroup $G_a$. Note that $G=\bigcup_a G_a$. If there are only finitely many subgroups, then $G$ is a finite union of finite groups. And of course if some $a$ generates a copy of $\mathbb{Z}$, we are also finished, since $\mathbb{Z}$ has infinitely many subgroups.

Comment: @ Andre Nicolas: We don't know that $G_a$ is finite. Is it possible that each $G_a=G$? Is it possible that $G$ does not contain a copy of $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: If $a$ has finite order, then $G_a$ is finite, so cannot be all of $G$. If $G_a$ is infinite, then $\mathbb{Z}$ is isomorphic to $G_a$ via the mapping that takes the integer $n$ (positive, negative, or $0$) to $a^n$.

Comment: @ Andre Nicolas: You wrote "If a has finite order, then $G_a$ is finite, so cannot be all of $ G$". Could you base it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A finite group certainly has only finitely many subgroups, so the question really boils down to this: is there an infinite group with only finitely many subgroups?

HINT: Let $G$ be an infinite group. Consider two cases:

1. Every element of $G$ has finite order.
2. $G$ contains an infinite cyclic subgroup.

What can you say in each case about the number of subgroups of $G$?

Comment: Could you elaborate your answer? I am not a specialist in group theory.

Comment: But presumably you're learning group theory, and this hint should suffice.

Comment: @ Mike: No, it is not sufficient information.

Comment: @user64494: Neither am I; I’m not even an algebraist. I don’t want to say too much more, because it’s already a fairly substantial hint. (1) If $x\in G$ has finite order, how big is the subgroup $\langle x\rangle$ of $G$? (2) Up to isomorphism there is only one infinite cyclic group, $\Bbb Z$; what subgroups does it have?

Comment: @ Brian M. Scott: Could you explain the first case in detail?

Comment: @ Brian M. Scott: Is it posible neither (1) nor (2) if a group is not abelian?

Comment: @user64494: Every element in every group generates a cyclic subgroup. Either all of those subgroups are finite, or one of them is infinite and therefore isomorphic to $\langle\Bbb Z,+\rangle$. It makes no difference whether $G$ is Abelian.

Comment: @ Brian M. Scott: Suppose each $G_a$ is finite. So what?

Comment: @user64494: Think about what you’re trying to prove. It’s staring you right in the face.

Comment: @ Brian M. Scott:  I got it.

Comment: @user64494: Excellent! That’s what I was hoping for.